# Colored Hexdump

Tags: color, listings

I want to print a hexdump in my document, where i color some specific bytes.
I tried working with *escapeinside* then doing *textcolor* in my *lstlisting* but this changes the format of the text. The bytes need to stay aligned.

Exampleoutput:
[image]

Examplecode:

```
\lstset{escapeinside={<@}{@>}}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=none, basicstyle=\scriptsize]
01b0    00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  78  56  34  12  <@\textcolor{blue}{00}@>  <@\textcolor{blue}{00}@>  00  01
01c0    <@\textcolor{blue}{01}@>    <@\textcolor{blue}{00}@>    <@\textcolor{blue}{83}@>   <@\textcolor{blue}{fe}@>     <@\textcolor{blue}{ff}@>    <@\textcolor{blue}{ff}@>    3f  00  00  00  41  29  54  02  00  fe
01d0    ff  ff  82  fe  ff  ff  80  29  54  02  fa  e7  1d  00  00  fe
01e0    ff  ff  83  fe  ff  ff  7a  11  72  02  fa  e7  1d  00  80  fe
01f0    ff  ff  05  fe  ff  ff  74  f9  8f  02  0c  83  6c  04  <@\textcolor{red}{55}@>     <@\textcolor{red}{aa}@>
\end{lstlisting}
```

Is there a way i can keep my font style of my *listing* within the *escapeinside*? 
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use `lstlisting` in the first place? A simple solution using `tabular` would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{color}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\ttfamily
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{17}c@{}}
  01b0 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 78 & 56 & 34 & 12 & \color{blue}{00} & \color{blue}{00} & 00 & 01 \\
  01c0 & \color{blue}{01} & \color{blue}{00} & \color{blue}{83} & \color{blue}{fe} & \color{blue}{ff} & \color{blue}{ff} & 3f & 00 & 00 & 00 & 41 & 29 & 54 & 02 & 00 & fe \\
  01d0 & ff & ff & 82 & fe & ff & ff & 80 & 29 & 54 & 02 & fa & e7 & 1d & 00 & 00 & fe \\
  01e0 & ff & ff & 83 & fe & ff & ff & 7a & 11 & 72 & 02 & fa & e7 & 1d & 00 & 80 & fe \\
  01f0 & ff & ff & 05 & fe & ff & ff & 74 & f9 & 8f & 02 & 0c & 83 & 6c & 04 & \color{red}{55} & \color{red}{aa} \\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works as well! Thanks for your help!